# Unable to set fileSystemInfo.lastModifiedDateTime on files on Sharepoint Online for some users since wednesday

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

We have created a multitenancy app, that uses graph api and app permission to access files in the tenants sharepoint document folder using the .net sdk.

Yesterday this stopped working for **some** of our tenants. We can upload a file to sharepoint, but when we change the LastModifiedDateTime to match the original file timestamp or rename a file, we get an error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException  Message: An
>   unspecified error has occurred

This has worked two days ago and the code hasn't changed. We tried to remove the app access from the tenant and reauthorize it.

I can't find anywhere to report that kind of error

UPDATE: There's also a bug where temporary tokens issues from Graph is invalid. This affects the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property on driveItem, the resumable upload function and download function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed, as more tenants are working again, but not all. We probably need to wait a few days before is't propagated to all servers

Comment: BokDamgaard - are you still seeing occurrences of this issue? If so I'd suggest adding a comment to the following GitHub issue with as much detail as you can provide (SPRequestGuid values are ideal): https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/832